# Same query gives different sort order in different environments. The versions of both environments are 2012, SP3 and SP4

Tags: database

Same query gives different sort order in different environments. The versions of both environments are 2012, SP3 and SP4. The query doesn't have an order by in it. The return values will be date and time. Group by clause is used.

Comment: Please clarify, which database do you use, what is your query, and what difference do you observe. Consider adding tags to your question.

Comment: This is a simple select query where we group the column like this,         
GROUP BY 
DATEPART(yy, CAST(CreatedDateTime AS DATETIME))
,DATEPART(wk, CAST(CreatedDateTime AS DATETIME))
,DATEPART(dy, CAST(CreatedDateTime AS DATETIME))
,DATEPART(hh, CAST(CreatedDateTime AS DATETIME)) on execution the query gives different sort order based on hour. ie hour part is not coming in asc order. @AlexanderGutenev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default in SQL Server. It’s an arbitrary sort.

It uses various plans to retrieve the data and store in temporary storage. If the plans are different, they’ll be retrieved in different orders.

To ensure the results are in an order you’re expecting, you need to supply an order by.

Answer (score 0):

SQL gives no guarantee about the order of rows returned unless you use an `order by` clause. There's no surprise different environments return different orders, in fact, it's almost to be expected (although it's probably unrelated to the different versions, but to how the data happens to be stored on the different environments' disks).

Comment: order in which the data stored in both environments are same. Do setting have any impact on sort order?